# Make bot create invite for every guild it is in

Tags: discord.js, commando

I want to know how to make it so every guild the bot is in, it will make an invite and put it in console. It keeps giving me all these ANNOYING typerrors.
`TypeError: Cannot read property 'first' of undefined`

I tried changing and messing with the variables.

```
  doopliss.on('ready', guild => {
    doopliss.guilds.channels.first().createInvite()
    .then(invite => console.log(invite.url))
    .catch(err => console.error());
  });
```

expect : bot that makes invites for every server it is in and posts it in console
actual result : bot dies and gives off annoying typeerrors

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use a `forEach()` loop to get *all* the guild invites. For example...

```js
doopliss.guilds.forEach(guild => {
  guild.channels.first().createInvite()
    .then(inv => console.log(`${guild.name} | ${inv.url}`));
    // Outputs the guild name + the invite URL
});
```

*See [`Map.forEach()`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/forEach).*

Comment: The only reason you were getting an undefined error is because you didn't specify which guild to take the invite from.

Comment: I had to slightly modify the code a little to get rid of some channels (as my bot created 2 servers) and then run this code for it to work. Console gave off a invalid console error but code works as is

Comment: Be careful with `forEach()`: because of its synchronous behavior, the promise returned by `GuildChannel.createInvite()` is still pending even when the loop is done. The loop is just making these calls and moving on, even if you use `await`. In this particular situation this shouldn't affect anything, but it's a worthy note.

Comment: dooplis is not defined

Answer (score 0):

### 2020 update

before you use `foreach()` ofc you need to use `.cache`

```
doopliss.guilds.cache.forEach(guild => {
         let channel = guild.channels.cache.last();
         createLink(channel,guild,message);
});


async function createLink(chan,guild,message) {
    let invite = await chan.createInvite().catch(console.error);
    try{
        message.channel.send(guild.name + '|' + invite);
    }catch (e) {
        message.channel.send(guild.name + '|' + 'no link available');
    }
}
```